# Unclear If statement functioning

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Can you explain the reason for unclear if statement functioning of ordinary code below?

```
numbers = "677 2584 238 3126 1366 646 2560 2439 543 379 1048 2053 2518 1496 2537 1983 118 2105 1175 145 311 1881"
listed_numbers = numbers.split(" ")
max = listed_numbers[0]
min = listed_numbers[0]
for each in listed_numbers:
    if each >= max:
        max = each
    if each <= min:
        min = each

print(str(max) + " " + str(min))
```

Code link attached
https://repl.it/join/grsvacto-nihilisticrefor

**PS** if question seems to be unclear or inaccurate, please indicate the fragment that is perplexing, or edit my questions. This will help me to ask the question later.

Comment: You should call Number(string) to convert from string to number

Comment: @chriptus13 I have debugged several times and couldn't understand a reason. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use comparison operators (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`) with string types instead of numerical types (int, float, etc), the two values are compared using alphabetical sorting to determine which one is greater - even if your string just contains numbers. Strings that start with a `1` will be sorted low, even if that string is `100`; strings that start with a `9` will be sorted high, even if that string is `9`.

For example, try this in your python REPL:

```
>>> 9 < 100
True
>>> "9" < "100"
False
```

As you can see, you're doing string comparison instead of numerical comparison. You need to convert your values to ints first. Instead of:

```
listed_numbers = numbers.split(" ")
```

… which just creates a list of strings, try:

```
listed_numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers.split(" ")]
```

… which converts each value to an int and creates a list of those using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) syntax.

Try your code with that one change and you'll get the output `3126 118`